# C# Export to excell

Tags: c#, excel, export

**ActionResult:**

```
var strLawTable = new StringBuilder();

    strLawTable.Append("<thead>");
    strLawTable.Append("<tr>");

    strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">Dollar</th>");

    strLawTable.Append("</tr>");
    strLawTable.Append("</thead>");   

strLawTable.Append("<tbody>");

foreach (Currency currency in Model.List)
{
strLawTable.Append("<tr>");

strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "</th>");

strLawTable.Append("</tr>");
}

strLawTable.Append("</tbody>");


string headerTable = "<table>" + strLawTable + "</table>";      

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestFile.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
sw.Write(headerTable);

System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

`GetExcellFormatString` method:

```
public string GetExcellFormatString(double doubleAmount) 
{
            if (doubleAmount < 1000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0.00");
            else if (doubleAmount < 1000000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0000.00");
            else if (doubleAmount < 1000000000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0000,000.00");
            else if (doubleAmount < 1000000000000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0000000000.00");
            else return doubleAmount.ToString();
}
```

My question:

My customers changed region settings on windows and they see

```
 3.50 as "May50"

20.50 as "Apr15"

etc..
```

Excel format is correct on my computer however on customer's computer it always displays date text.

I also **tried below** however still same problem

```
byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerTable);

return File(fileContents, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Test.xls");
```

I tried so much solutions (return file etc ) where I miss exactly, what do I need to add?

I can use `return file` or anything in `ActionResult`, I only need solution .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line

```
strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "</th>");
```

as :

```
strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">=\"" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "\"</th>");
```

notice the =\" and \" after  and before <\th>

Comment: It worked :) Thank you so much my friend.I only want to ask one more question to you . I can not summ Dollars inside of excell file.Because it is string it displays "100.00" it must be 100.00 how can i solve this if you know also this thanks

Comment: glad it helped. Don't forget to mark my answer as answer (heheheh greedy me :P), and why sum up the dollars in excel, instead sum them up in your code and then put them in excel.

Comment: customer wants to sum selected row's dollar that is why i am asking and i did not understand what did you mean last sentence thanks

Comment: what i meant was, add the dollars value in your code itself. don't leave the summing up of data in excel. add all the values of your usd, then add a <tr><td> for displaying that total. that's it. Tell you want to display sum of Currency.USD value's right? If that is what you want, post it in other question, i won't be able to help you out here as it won't allow me to talk to you much in comments. just post your query as another question, me or someone else will answer it. :)

Comment: After exported excell file. Customer wants to sum 1. row and 3. row and 7. row etc (Depends on customer) by hand. He press to "ctrl" and choose with mouse and select any row he wants after that he write query in excell file and sum selected rows.He can not sum because rows are string "100" etc.It must be 100 in order him to sum.

Comment: i won't be able to help you out here as it won't allow me to talk to you much in comments. just post your query as another question, me or someone else will answer it. :)

Comment: Thanks please check my new question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621609/c-sharp-excell-row-format