# C# Export to Excel format

Tags: c#, excel, format

**ActionResult:**

```
var strLawTable = new StringBuilder();

strLawTable.Append("<thead>");
strLawTable.Append("<tr>");

strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">Dollar</th>");

strLawTable.Append("</tr>");
strLawTable.Append("</thead>");   

strLawTable.Append("<tbody>");

foreach (Currency currency in Model.List)
{
strLawTable.Append("<tr>");

strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">=\"" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "\"</th>");

strLawTable.Append("</tr>");
}

strLawTable.Append("</tbody>");


string headerTable = "<table>" + strLawTable + "</table>";      

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestFile.xls");
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
Response.BinaryWrite(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
sw.Write(headerTable);

System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

`GetExcellFormatString` method:

```
public string GetExcellFormatString(double doubleAmount) 
{
            if (doubleAmount < 1000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0.00");
            else if (doubleAmount < 1000000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0000.00");
            else if (doubleAmount < 1000000000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0000,000.00");
            else if (doubleAmount < 1000000000000)
                return doubleAmount.ToString("0000000000.00");
            else return doubleAmount.ToString();
}
```

My question:

After I exported the data into an Excel file, I have values in my Excel table below,

Exported Excel table

**Dollar**

```
50.0

35.0

40.0

60.0


etc..
```

If I **press** to "**ctrl**" and **click** with mouse 35.0 and 40.0 Excel **can not sum 35.0 and 40.0** because **35.0 is string displays "35.0" and 40.0 is string displays "40.0"**.

The problem is about sum selected rows however I can not sum because values are string not numeric

How can I remove **" "** out of string number in Excel table by C# code ?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you try using another decimal separator, `,` instead of `.`?

Comment: i have to put . any solutions please ?

Comment: why not just remove the quotes from your string? change `strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">=\"" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "\"</th>");
` to -> `strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">=" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "</th>");`

Comment: @chancea your answer is the best of the best. it worked.this was what i looked for all day today.. Please answer and i will accept it best answer thank you so much

Comment: @Richard glad it worked, I posted that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the quotes change this line:

```
strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">=\"" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "\"</th>");
                                                     ^^remove                                     ^^remove
```

to this:

```
strLawTable.Append("<th style=\"text-align: right\">=" + GetExcellFormatString(Currency.USD) + "</th>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using third party libraries, there is this solution:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/692092/A-free-Export-to-Excel-Csharp-class-using-OpenXML

It uses [OpenXML](http://www.wikiwand.com/pl/Office_Open_XML) library (available through nuget).

It works like a charm - well, if there are only integers and strings in your data. It can be customized, though. The method to look at is `WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(DataTable dt, WorksheetPart worksheetPart)`, where you'll have to take care of different data types (`Double`, `Decimal`, `DateTime`...). I also recomend using `number.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` when getting string values of numeric columns. Otherwise there will be the same problem that you have: the column won't be recognized as a correct number (at best it will be a text column, or there will be error in the cell).

You can also set up custom formatting of numbers in your column (if you really have to use specific formatting for your numbers): http://lateral8.com/articles/2010/6/11/openxml-sdk-20-formatting-excel-values.aspx